# Getting all records based off given SObjectType

Tags: apex, soql

So my objective is to get all the records with fields based off a user selected SObjecttype.

```
public List<SObject> getAll(String SOType)
```

i know I can get all the fields using

```
SObjectType Type=Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(SOType);
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = Type.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

I'm stuck on the SOQL part to get the records. Can you do a query based off a generic SObject? How do you get the fields in? I don't recall Select * being an option in SOQL.

Or is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would just do a comma join on the fields and build a dynamic query string:

```
// renamed SOType to sObjectType
DescribeSObjectResult describe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectType);
List<String> fields = new List<String>(describe.fields.getMap().keySet());
String soql = String.format(
    'SELECT {0} FROM {1}', new List<String> {
        String.join(fields, ','), sObjectType
    }
);
```

Then you can use the `Database.query` method:

```
List<SObject> records = Database.query(soql);
```

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer! minor typo. should be getGlobalDescribe()